# Windows like flat cursor for Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, cursor, cursor-theme

I am finding a flat cursor (like in Windows) for ubuntu. Default ubuntu cursor has a very thik border. And the selection cursor (cusror used while you select text) looks very ugly with the thik black borders.

I was searching for it but unable to find it. Do anyone know how/where to get it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get Windows 8 cursors in Ubuntu.

1. Download it

   ```
   wget https://dl.opendesktop.org/api/files/download/id/1460735137/155025-win8.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract it

   ```
   tar xvf 155025-win8.tar.gz
   ```
3. Move it to /usr/share/icons

   ```
   sudo mv win8 /usr/share/icons/ -v
   ```

After that, select the cursor theme named **Win8** from Unity Tweak tool and Apply.

Here is lots of cursor theme to choose https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/107/ord/latest/

The installation procedure are almost always with the post. It's easy to apply the cursor theme.

Comment: `wget` now gives the error `Connecting to dl.opendesktop.org (dl.opendesktop.org)|206.81.27.185|:443... failed: Connection refused.

`